# Rest Framework - How to apply field-level permissions after create/update?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have implemented field-level permissions by overriding get_fields() as follows:

```
    def get_fields(self):
        viewable_fields = {}
        fields = super().get_fields()
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        model = self.Meta.model
        model_name = model._meta.model_name
        try:
            user = request.user
        except AttributeError:
            return viewable_fields

        for field_name in fields:
            if user.has_perm('view_' + model_name + '_' + field_name):
                viewable_fields[field_name] = fields[field_name]

        return viewable_fields
```

That works fine for list and detail views, but when I tried to apply that mixin to create/update views, the nested fields were empty.  I have removed it from create/update views, but then I get **all** fields returned after the operation is completed.  For example, there's an "internal_notes" field that users with "team" group can view, but others cannot.  If I "patch" an update by one of the users who cannot view that field, the "internal_notes" field is returned after the update process completes.

Note that I do not pass the "internal_notes" field in the update.  I do partial updates (with PATCH), so in my test I only passed "initials" as the field to change.

Here's an edited version (some fields omitted for brevity) of the result from a detail view. Note: no "internal_notes", which is correct.

```
    "results": {
        "id": 1,
        "client": "Acme Honey",
        "url": "http://demo1.mysite.api/clients/team/1/",
        "team_member": {
            "id": 5,
            "url": "http://demo1.mysite.api/users/team/5/",
            "user": {
                "id": 5,
                "username": "Angela Tate",
                "first_name": "Angela",
                "last_name": "Tate",
                "initials": "AT",
                "status": "Active"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what is returned after the update - including "internal_notes" (which is not correct):

```
    "results": {
        "id": 1,
        "client": "Acme Honey",
        "url": "http://demo1.mysite.api/clients/team/1/",
        "team_member": {
            "id": 5,
            "url": "http://demo1.mysite.api/users/team/5/",
            "user": {
                "id": 5,
                "username": "Angela Tate",
                "first_name": "Angela",
                "last_name": "Tate",
                "initials": "XX",
                "status": "Active",
                "internal_notes": "My test notes"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The structure is:

- Top level: ClientTeamMember

  - Nested field: TeamMember (team_member in the results above)

    - Nested field: User (user in the results above)

Here are the models:

```
class ClientTeamMember(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    team_member = models.ForeignKey(TeamMember, on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class TeamMember(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class User(AbstractUser):

    initials = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    internal_notes = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
```

The serializers:

```
class ClientTeamMemberSaveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='name',
        queryset=Client.objects.all(),
    )
    team_member = TeamMemberSaveSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ClientTeamMember
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Get the request to pass to other serializers, so they can get the current user.
        try:
            request = self.context.get('request', None)
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            request = None

        team_member = instance.team_member
        team_member_data = validated_data.pop('team_member', None)

        if team_member_data is not None:
            serializer = TeamMemberSaveSerializer(
                data=team_member_data,
                partial=True,
                context={'request': request}
            )
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.update(team_member, serializer.validated_data)

        return super().update(instance, validated_data)


class TeamMemberSaveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSaveSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = TeamMember
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Get the request to pass to other serializers, so they can get the current user.
        try:
            request = self.context.get('request', None)
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            request = None

        user = instance.user
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')

        serializer = UserSaveSerializer(
            data=user_data,
            partial=True,
            context={'request': request}
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.update(user, serializer.validated_data)
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)


class UserSaveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        .
        . Other code omitted for brevity
        .
        user = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        return user
```

So the question is: where in the create/update processes can I apply field-level permissions and return the correct results?  I thought about spinning through serializer.data after the update and removing fields that don't have sufficient permissions, but I need model name to build the permission codename string, and in the "data" structure, the nested fields don't have model_name available (as far as I can see).